# Order by from different table column very slowly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

- I have two tables (**table1**, **table2**)
- **table1** has 20000000 records
- **table2** has 0 records
- **table1** has clustered index with ID and nonclustered index with ID2 ,**table2** have cluster index with ID
- the following query is very fast:

  ```
  select top 100 table1.Name,table2.Name 
  from table1 WITH (NOLOCK) left join table2 on table1.ID2= table2.ID 
  order by table1.ID desc'
  ```
- the following query takes a long time to execute:

  ```
  select top 100 table1.Name,table2.Name 
  from table1 WITH (NOLOCK) left join table2 on table1.ID2= table2.ID 
  order by table1.ID desc,table2.ID desc'
  ```

This is the execution plan:

[image]

What can I do for excute sql with `order by table1.ID desc,table2.ID desc`?

Comment: This is a bit contrived because the second table is empty. What happens when that second table has actual data, and isn't that the more realistic use case here?

Comment: actual situation is table2 will only have 10 records

Comment: Duplicating this with the code here http://rextester.com/YKTHXB31408 shows no difference in execution plans on my SQL Server 2017, tested up to 200000 rows in table1. Can you confirm the structures and indexes are similar to yours?

Comment: Can you put ' OPTION (RECOMPILE)' at the end of both statements and see if there is any difference? It could be a bad plan in the cache for the second statement.

Comment: @DirkMa It is not showing a difference in the execution. I think that the clustered index on uniqueidentifier might be the problem. If you are moving the data for every insert that has been made (because the guid is random by nature) you quickly fragment the table, also causing harm to the disk is possible. Can you rebuild the clustered index and try again? Look at properties of index PK_Table1 to see if it is fragmented.

Comment: @cloudsafe thanks,it works ^^,thank you so much!But there is other problem![http://rextester.com/IFMQ75306](http://rextester.com/IFMQ75306) if sort with 'order by table2.name desc,table1.ID desc' is so slowly,do you have some better suggest? by the way i love you so much!

Comment: @DirkMa Thank you for the appreciation<3. Although, I cannot duplicate the slowness, but question the need to sort by a uniqueidentifier. Is there a reason to do this? If not, don't sort by table1.ID Desc. Otherwise, this index might help: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Table1_id2_inc_id_name] ON [dbo].[Table1] ([id2] desc) INCLUDE ([id], [name])

Comment: @cloudsafe thanks for you help.in my case i must sort by uniqueidentifier and it must at the end of order by.i will try more ways.thanks! ^^

Answer (score 0):

The left join means that every row in table1 will be guaranteed to contribute at least one row to the result and you never need more than 100 rows from that table.

So I would try

```
WITH T1Top100
     AS (SELECT TOP 100 *
         FROM   table1
         ORDER  BY ID DESC)
SELECT TOP 100 table1.NAME,
               table2.NAME
FROM   T1Top100 table1
       LEFT JOIN table2
              ON table1.ID2 = table2.ID
ORDER  BY table1.ID DESC,
          table2.ID DESC
```

Comment: thanks for your answer,actually the above query is a statement within the view, but I can't modify that view, i just can use select col1,col2 from v1 order by col1,col2.